# Is any utterance in English used only by men or only by women?

Tags: interjections, sociolinguistics

In my native language, there are some interjections used only by women. For example *Va* (pronounced /vʌ/), is an exclamation used to express surprise only by women. If any man happens to use them, he will be either laughed at and humiliated, or will be considered a man with female characteristics.

Are there any similar things in English which should be avoided to be used by men (or women) and one should be aware of?

The example I used was an interjection, but your answer might be any word, phrase, idiom that could be thought of.

Comment: You probably should put a time frame on your question. In the recent past, there were many words that no self-respecting lady would have used. Today, the use of such terms by females is (in some circles) regarded as a mark of equality.

Comment: @Fortiter; the point about such language was that it was not used either by a lady or a gentleman. Fishwives and longshoremen (for example) were under no such restrictions. [Nothing personal.]

Comment: This is, um, more complicated than it might appear. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_and_gender), [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavender_linguistics),  [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/02/28/science/young-women-often-trendsetters-in-vocal-patterns.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0), [here](http://www.ucc.ie/publications/heeu/womenstf/3_conrick.htm), and [here](http://www.venusboyz.com/PDF/DissertationFVoegeli.pdf) — just for starters.

Comment: I don't know about exclusive use, but there's just a huge set of culturally one-sided words that will separate the sexes in general (but those in the field won't care). 'What brand of jock strap do you use?' I think is pretty rarely used (or asked of) women. Like ceteris paribus 'panty-liner'.

Comment: @tchrist Your links to discussions of related subjects are really good and really fascinating, and worth reading. I might have missed something in all of that, but it still seems to me that they nevertheless don't present any word or phrase that fits what the OP is looking for. Although word frequency, intonations and inflections, partial forms of speech, etc., etc., might reflect different ways people have of speaking based on their gender, none of this seems to supply a specific word or phrase that satisfies the condition stated in the question.

Comment: @Meysam Nowadays I do not hear much "VAs" from women, young or old and in my childhood ages I heard it only from Tehrani natives (People who are from Tehran the capital of Iran originally) and Isfahani natives (People who are from Isfahan city) not from South of Iran like my own hometown Ahvaz or north of Iran or from Kurds or Turks. It would be better to edit your question and make it more accurate to give correct information to people who are not familiar with Iranians and Farsi language and its different dialects.

Answer (score 4):

I accidentally came across this on Wikipedia. It is a page about the [Geordie dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geordie) in the north of the UK:

> **Phonology**
>  There is some differentiation in pronunciation in the Geordie dialect based upon the speaker's sex. For example, English
>   sound /aʊ/, pronounced generically in Geordie as [əʊ], may also have
>   other, more specific pronunciations depending upon whether one is male
>   or female. Males alone often pronounce the sound /aʊ/ as [uː], for
>   example, the word house (/haʊs/) pronounced as [huːs]. Females, on the
>   other hand, will often pronounce this sound as [eʉ], thus: [heʉs].

Sorry I can't add more, I'm not that familiar with Geordie pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such words in English.

Comment: Surely such "certainty" should be supported by some evidence.

Comment: @Fortiter: how do you propose a negative should be proved?

Comment: @TimLymington Not proved, perhaps, but at least supported. I can, off the top of my head, think of several such possible supports, such as "English grammar is mostly gender-neutral, so exclamations are less likely to be gender-specific as well". Such a strong statement should have *some* pretense at a solid basis.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan We aren’t talking about grammatical gender here; we’re talking about the speaker’s actual sex. Therefore the comparative paucity of grammatical gender in English is completely immaterial. The question is whether there are any words that are exclusively used by only one sex but not the other.

Comment: I don't see why you would seperate vocabulary and grammar here. Words that are constructed using grammatical rules of gender certainly could have different usages. The same word, inflected differently, will carry different connotations, and as such might be commonly used only by one gender or another.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Stick to the question: The question is whether there are words, _not_ gender specific, which are _used_ by only one gender. It would be easy enough to say that a man would not say, "I have a uterus" (you can't get much more grammatically gender-specific than that), but this is absolutely irrelevant to the question. And the suggestion that a difference in inflection might suggest usage by only one gender is also not to the point. Nor do you provide any examples of such usage. Don't try to force the question to fit the answer.

Comment: @Fortiter I take your point about providing support whenever possible, but Tim is right. Logically there's no way to prove the point. I could have used qualified verbiage, such as, "In my experience, I have never encountered such words, and so in my opinion, it doesn't seem any exist." But I think users of the site can grasp, especially in a case wherein a statement like that is _not_ accompanied by specifically referenced support, that it is the opinion of the writer, filtered through the writer's experience and knowledge. Do I really _need_ to add, therefore, that it's my opinion?

Comment: But, for fun and completeness, let me give the expanded version of my answer: "Having written hundreds of thousands of words (professionally), edited magazines, taught college writing courses, absorbed thousands of books, TV shows, and films, and spoken with literally hundreds of thousands of people, and having explored and pondered English for decades, I feel that, based on my experience and my understanding of the language, the likelihood that one will discover a word that entirely qualifies as gender-linked in the way you describe is exceptionally low."

Comment: And people can keep downvoting this answer all they want, but even so, as I write this, not one single valid example of the type of usage being sought has yet been presented by anyone. And only one single valid example is all it would take to prove this answer logically incorrect. I'll be happy to admit I was wrong if anyone can come up with something. I'm waiting.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg Perhaps I should have been blunter in saying that your long answer (as given in the comment) was what was originally required. Whether your statement "I am not aware of any" is a good approximation to "There are none" rests entirely upon the reputation of the speaker. "How can I prove a negative?" is a straw man that if accepted would allow any unsupported negative assertion.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg There are no Persian words too and the OP is giving wrong information and is unfortunately rejecting my edits. It is a kind of dialect,very localized and belongs to many years ago not nowadays. I have to add there is a culture behind this. Men who were using it had been considered homosexual or gay and in the eyes of majority it was a negative remark (And even nowadays in eyes of many people but I am not sure about the majority). There is also a remark for them in Persian language taken of "VA" which is "Eva Khahar".

Comment: "Eva"="Va"=Oh! and "Khahar"=sister! so "Eva Khahar"= Oh my sister! Then: Eva khahar = Gay

Comment: @Fortiter I say, sir, that I respect you requesting support for my answer, and I said as much in my first comment. I also agree that my long answer is superior, and even preferable. But I will reassert my point that I think it a reasonable assumption that users of this site recognize that all answers are necessarily opinion, especially so when you consider that there really are no absolute, hard and fast, inviolable, prescriptive "rules" of English grammar. I think even John Lawler, whom I take to be the most knowledgeable authority using this site regularly, would likely agree with that.

Comment: @Fortiter And further, Tim Lymington's point about proving a negative is a simple, very well known point of logic. You CAN'T prove a negative. If I say there are no pink elephants, it may or may not be true, but there is no way to PROVE that it is true. Yet at any moment, if a pink elephant appears, the statement has been instantly DISproven. And I reiterate, I would be happy to be proven wrong in my assertion that there are no words such as that which the OP seeks; disproving my statement would take only one such word. But even now, I see none offered by anyone. I'm still waiting.

Answer (score -1):

"Let's go to the bathroom."

Girls go in clusters.  Ask a guy to join you and he'll be more than a little weirded out.

There are a lot of off-color slang phrases.  Guys typically can't get away with certain terms without it being significantly more offensive.

"Fabulous" is a term a straight guy will rarely use.

Comment: Oh no, not [lavender linguistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavender_linguistics)!

Comment: I cannot believe someone took the time to write that all out, let alone study it.

Comment: "Let's go to the bathroom" is used here to stand in for _any_ verbiage used to ask someone to accompany the speaker to the bathroom. It thus refers to a sociological tendency, not to an actual word or phrase which links to one gender; therefore it does not qualify. The "slang phrase" portion of the answer gives no specifics, and so can hardly be discussed. And "fabulous," well, it might be ever-so-slightly more common for gay men to say it, but I don't think it's a strong enough association to count as a good answer, especially in our modern, metrosexual world.

Comment: On what basis do you state that "'Fabulous' is a term a straight guy will rarely use." and in what country / area / culture are you suggesting that that is the case?

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps "I'm blonde" will qualify: in British English, the spelling would usually be blond for a male. The difference in spelling is obvious in writing; pronunciation is less clearly differentiated, in my experience. This is, to my knowledge, the one adjective in English where the inflection for gender from the language of origin is (at least to some extent) preserved ( http://grammarist.com/usage/blond-blonde/ ).

Comment: The old *naïf/naïve* distinction has run a bit thin, but you’ll hear women in America of Hispanic heritage refer to themselves as *latinas* not as *latinos*.

Comment: This is an answer to a different question than was asked.  The original poster asked for a word that was used only ***by*** one but and not the other, not for one used ***for*** one sex but not the other.  Therefore, *blonde/blond* no more counts than *hers/his* might — or *girl/boy*.

Comment: @tchrist, agreed - despite the subtlety of blond/blonde, this answer is really no different than "I'm a woman!" or "I'm female!", which doesn't get at what the question is looking for.

Comment: Despite the fact that Edwin's answer might be not quite what the OP was looking for, I would simply like to point out that the spelling of the word, at least in AmE, and at least in many print instances I've encountered, is dictated by the usage: "Blonde" is the noun meaning a person who has blond hair ("he/she is a blonde"), and "blond" is the adjective describing the color of the hair.

Comment: @tchrist All your comments are great, but the one about _latinas_ doesn't support your other points. _Latina_ is just an example of Spanish language gender-designated usage, such as _amiga_ meaning female friend, as opposed to _amigo_ meaning male friend. It equates to "boy/girl." "I am a Latino," equates (for most current speakers) to saying "I am a male person of that ethnic descent," so a woman would not say it on a purely factual basis, not by gender preference. (Leaving aside sociological and medical issues such as transsexualism.)